# Use of abstract Dao method in database class

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have been quite inquisitive on the reason why an abstract Dao method  is used to access the methods in the the Dao interface in android room database

Comment: It is just to prevent exposure of actual implementation on consumer's side. I.e. if you annotate a DAO method with insert tag then you don't wanna know how it's implemented by ROOM. All you care about is that it is responsible to insert records to your desired database.

Answer (score 0):

it is not just the Room, Retrofit and other libraries use this pattern too, it is called Programming to an Interface. Instead of just creating a concrete implementation you just specify the stuff you want to do and they provide you with an implementation that will behave as you requested.

For further study you can check this article: https://tuhrig.de/programming-to-an-interface/